# UI Automation: which delegate methods are called when scrolling in a scrollview

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, ios4, uiscrollview, ios-ui-automation

I'm new to UIAutomation introduced by iOS4. I'm scripting a test which requires to scroll in a scrollview.

So `UIAScrollView` has the following methods:

- scrollUp
- scrollDown
- scrollLeft
- scrollRight
- scrollToElementWithName
- scrollToElementWithPredicate
- scrollToElementWithValueForKey

I want to know which `UIScrollView` delegate methods are invoked in the app when using these functions in my script.

Answer (score 1):

UI Automation has nearly nothing to do with your Application in fact you can even run automation for apps that aren't yours. Indeed you have to know the accessibility label for each element. Therefore it should call the normal `UIScrollViewDelegate` which contains:

```
Responding to Scrolling and Dragging
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:

Managing Zooming
– viewForZoomingInScrollView:
– scrollViewWillBeginZooming:withView:
– scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:
– scrollViewDidZoom:

Responding to Scrolling Animations
– scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:
```

simply implement all into your application and `NSLog()` which one gets called.
Not sure if that's what you wanted to know.

Comment: I'm sure that I can't use UI Automation for apps that are not my own. I've tested that on my device. The UI Automation script pauses when I switch to other apps. However sometimes it works in the simulator to control other apps. But that wasn't my question. I could use NSLog in each of the delegate methods, but I was too lazy to do that - thats why I asked it here.

Comment: it cannot be run on other apps? my fault, haven't done anything with it yet, sorry.

Comment: You should be able to use UIAutomation on apps that aren't your own, but you have to bind to that app process in Instruments.  You can't switch processes in the middle of a trace.